# node js promise return data is Promise { _45: 0, _81: 0, _65: null, _54: null }

Tags: node.js

i have two file one for code is to find data from mongo database, and anothe file have stored the data according to first file data.

in generate id ,code is written as

```
function findID(name) {
    return new promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        GenerateID.find(
            { "id_name": name },
            { "id_code": 1, "id_value": 1, "_id": 0 },
            function (err, genvalue) {
                if (err) {

                    return (console.log('error has been occured to find database id name'));
                }
                if (genvalue == null) {
                    return resolve(false);
                }
                else {
                    var stringifyval = JSON.stringify(genvalue);
                    stringifyval = stringifyval.replace('[', ' ').replace(']', ' ');
                    var data = JSON.parse(stringifyval);
                    var id = data.id_code + "" + String(data.id_value);
                    console.log(id);
                    return resolve(id);
                }
            });
    });
}
```

and in another file has calling above method data

```
var GetIDPromise = GenerateID.findID(name);
GetIDPromise.then(function (val) {
    console.log(val);
    name = val;
});
console.log(name);
```

but i am getting  return result  is

`Promise { _45: 0, _81: 0, _65: null, _54: null }`

please help me as what code to written in two different file. one for calling return data and another for accessing method

Comment: from mongo database the result is coming as id_code ="RE" and id Value =1 and then i am concatenating the result and pass to another page method in terms of return and so data is used as code to update in database.

Comment: Could you try to replace the line `return resolve( id );` with just `resolve( id );` and report back here?